# sending/receiving messages from/to hornetQ from SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008, hornetq

I need to create a stored procedure in SQL server 2008 which can create and post a message to HornetQ. I did some searches and looks like I have 2 options :

- registering an assembly in sql server which can be used to create
  and send the message but is there a libarary that I can use for this
  purpose or we have to develop our own ?
- Using HornetQ REST APIs however I have no idea if this is possible and if yes how can I do it ?

and my last question : is it possible to consume messages inside sql server (even with a scheduled job which is running every minute) and if yes , how ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could connect a stomp .net client. I believe you can use C# or VB on a SQL Server store procedure

Comment: thx for your answer but having a stomp .net client means opening and closing the connection to HornetQ every time we want to send a message and the user manual says that this anti pattern and will result in poor performance. correct ?

Comment: You could cache your connection Somehow on the .net side.
Message systems are meant to performance. and if you open a connection and close it every time you send a message, you will be doing a lot of unecessary round trips through network, being bound to latency. 

The best is always to cache connections. And this goes to any message system. It's a general concept (nothing specific to HornetQ). Use this tip on any message system you chose.